# how to filter float64 values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that I want to filter with pandas. This is what the csv file looks like

```
Name            Employee ID
Jane Doe        00101848707829
Jason Smith     0030201689375900
Jason Bourne    0017501001410513
...
```

I want only that data where the `Employee ID` starts with `001`. So the filtered results would look like this

```
Name            Employee ID
Jane Doe        00101848707829
Jason Bourne    0017501001410513
```

This is my code

```
df_filter = df.loc[:, df['Employee ID'].str.startswith("890")]
```

The problem is that the datatype of `Employee ID` is `float64`. So I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-de57783153c3> in <module>
----> 1 df_filter = df.loc[:, df['Employee ID'].str.startswith("001")]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5268             or name in self._accessors
   5269         ):
-> 5270             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5271         else:
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
    185             # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    186             return self._accessor
--> 187         accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    188         # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    189         # http://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in __init__(self, data)
   2039 
   2040     def __init__(self, data):
-> 2041         self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
   2042         self._is_categorical = is_categorical_dtype(data)
   2043         self._is_string = data.dtype.name == "string"

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in _validate(data)
   2096 
   2097         if inferred_dtype not in allowed_types:
-> 2098             raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
   2099         return inferred_dtype
   2100 

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

how do I filter `float64` data using `startswith`?

Comment: `[df['Employee ID'] = [df['Employee ID'].astype(str)` and then `df_filter = df[df['Employee ID'].str.startswith("001")]` Your syntax is off.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df_filter = df[df['Employee ID'].apply(lambda x: str(x).startswith('001'))]
```

OR, use [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Employee ID'] = [df['Employee ID'].astype(str)
df_filter = df[df['Employee ID'].str.startswith("001")]
```